# Does anybody knows origin and reference Buddha teaches a bossy & angry the seven kinds of wifes

Tags: merit, sila, lay-practices, paramitas

**... in letting her chose which kind she would like to be?**

Valued Upasaka, Upasika,
Dear seekers for the way to Awakening and Readers,

Atma (polite addressing of the own person toward householders, where Atma dwells) has started the transcribtion and translation of a very seldom teaching in modern and western world in regard of the Maha Manala Sutta by Ven. K. Gunaratana Thera, still not finished. Most stories are taken from the Jataka, some references already found. In redard of "To Look After Feed And Take Care Of The Wife And Children Is Most Blissful/highest protection" it contains a story that goes this:

> Sujata, the sister of Visakha Maha Upasika, married the son of Anata Pindika. She was not only wealthy but was also charming. In the home of Anata Pindika she became disagreeable to almost every member of the family and to the servants as well. She was very quarrelsome and had her own say mostly because of her conceit.
>
> One day Anata Pindika offered food to the Lord Buddha and his Bhikkhus and during the meal, she made a commotion in the household. The Lord Buddha,knowing the nature of the woman enquired about her dispute, which disrupted the peace of the home. The Lord Buddha then asked her, “There are seven classes of wives; have you any knowledge to which class you belong?” She replied that she did not know. The Lord Buddha said, “A wife not in any way agreeable but finding every chance to quarrel with her husband or members of his family, is a quarrelsome wife. A wife whose outlook in life is bent on squandering away the fortune of her husband in gambling or drinking, is a thievish wife, a wife who takes good advantage of the kindness of her husband, adopts a superior outlook in a manner so as to gain control over him in any matter concerning his family or his outside activities, is a
> domineering wife; but when a wife looks after her husband’s interest with tender care and devotion like a mother over her child, this kind of wife is a motherly one; again a wife who by nature is obedient and shy like a sister to a brothers belongs to a sisterly type; and a wife who shares in like manner the happiness of misfortune of her husband is at once a friendly one; finally a wife who lives in tolerance of the whims and dislikes of her husband and serves him faithfully throughout, is a servantly type.
> In the light of the truth Sujata gained the realization of the fruits of the First Path (Sotapatti).
> Continuing the sermon, the Lord Buddha remarked that among the first three classes of wives, their existence after death would be in a hellish state, suffering untold pain in the unconsuming fire or
> tortment. The remaining four classes of wives would enjoy even in their present lives, the store of
> happiness and after death, their existence would be in a continued state of bliss in the realm of heaven.

1. Does anybody know the reference in the Suttapitaka (thinking Atma came accross one time there)?
2. Does anybody know which Ven. K. Gunaratana Thera wrote this book and some infos, biography and picture of him? Maybe even contact possibility, if still alive?
3. If inspired and knowing also the references of other stories in the book, willing to research them, feel invited to take on this possibility.

(If somebody feels inspired to help prove reading and/or translating further, one should feel welcome to take this possibility. Topic as well as sources can be found here: [Mangala Sutta Uannana - Ven. K. Gunaratana Thera(draft)](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,309.msg649.html#msg649)

*(Note, this question and content is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commerzial use or other purpose of wordily gains.)*

Answer (score 1):

Atta feels inspired to help translating further this sutta Atma is searching for. Below are seven translations of the seven wives sutta:

1.[සුජාතඝර සුණ්හා සූත්‍රය](https://suttacentral.net/si/an7.63)

2.[妻子經](https://suttacentral.net/zh/an7.63)

3.[Жёны](https://suttacentral.net/ru/an7.63)

4.[Các Người Vợ](https://suttacentral.net/vn/an7.63)

5.[ภริยาสูตร](https://suttacentral.net/th/an7.63)

6.[Az erőd](https://suttacentral.net/hu/an7.63)

7.[Istri-Istri](https://suttacentral.net/id/an7.63)

With metta

Householder # 3,454,845,812

Comment: There is a German version as well (among others): https://suttacentral.net/de/an7.63
And in English: http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/4Anguttara-Nikaya/Anguttara4/7-sattakanipata/006-abyakatavaggo-e.html (10. Bhariyāsuttaṃ - Wives)

Comment: You could make this answer shorter and clearer, by saying something like, "The 'seven wives' sutta is *Bhariyāsutta* (AN 7.63). There's [a copy of it on SuttaCentral](https://suttacentral.net/pi/an7.63), with [various translations of it](https://suttacentral.net/an7) into 11 languages including English and German. With metta."

Comment: Risky sometimes...

Comment: The Buddha taught to be grateful for the small favour or gift. The sutta requested was provided. The Buddha said rare is the world is a thankful & grateful person. This appears very true.